# Proving sum of digits of $111111...^2$ is square of sum of digits of $11111...$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do you prove that the sum of the digits of the square of a number comprised solely of ones is the square of the sum of the digits of that number?

For instance, the sum of digits of $111^2$ is 9, which is the square of $3$.

Is there an elegant proof for this using number theory and modulos? Perhaps something using modulos of $3$ or $9$ as in those cases the remainder is the same as the sum of the digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true.

The digital sum of 1111111111 is 10. But its square is 1234567900987654321, whose digital sum is only 82, due to carries.

Comment: I see - then why in this problem: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/2009_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_5 does the solution perform this method? Is it because there are no carries? How would the author have known there were no carries without carrying out the full mulitplication?

Comment: @1110101001: That one is specifically for 111111111 (with 9 ones), not for all one-repdigits in general. If you carry out the multiplication $111111111^2$ on paper, you will quickly realize why there are no carries in that (or shorter) cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you iterate the digital sum until you are left with a single digit, the claim is true.

To prove it show that the iterated digital sum of $n$ is $n\mod 9$.